# Is it possible to migrate Artifacts from one Organization to another?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, migration, azure-artifacts

I am a bit clueless if it's possible or not, my current task from my senior is to migrate project scoped feeds from one azure devops organisation.
I tried it via REST API, but all I got were empty .nupkg package files.

Is there any possible way to solve this, maybe a native solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can use the [Artifact Details - Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [NuGet - Download Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API successfully download the .nupkg package files to a folder (here is `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1\package\`).

Here is my sample:

```
$PAT=""
$orgname=""
$projectname=""
$feedname=""
$PATGetBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")
$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PATGetBytes)
$Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication) }
$Uri = "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/"+$orgname+"/"+$projectname+"/_apis/packaging/Feeds/"+$feedname+"/packages?api-version=7.0"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'
$response | ConvertTo-Json
$packagenames=$response.value.name
$packageversions=$response.value.versions.version

for ( $index = 0; $index -lt $packagenames.count; $index++)
{
        $packagename=$packagenames[$index]
        $packageversion=$packageversions[$index]
        echo $packagename $packageversion
        $filePATH= "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1\package\"
        $filename=$filePATH+$packagename+"."+$packageversion+".nupkg"
        $Uri2= "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/"+$orgname+"/"+$projectname+"/_apis/packaging/feeds/"+$feedname+"/nuget/packages/"+$packagename+"/versions/"+$packageversion+"/content?api-version=7.0-preview"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri2 -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/zip" -OutFile $filename
}
```

Then I can use the nuget push command to push them to a new feed.
If you run the powershell in pipeline, then you can use the NuGet push task with a service connection of Target feed location. (I use
`$filePATH = "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\"` to replace `$filePATH= "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1\package\"` in the powershell Script when I run the powershll task in pipeline)
[image]